# Application getting crashed at upload image in AWS S3 bucket for swift 3

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, swift3, aws-sdk

In my application, I am trying to upload image using AWS S3. But, When i am selecting image from library or captured image,in uploading process my application is getting crashed.

```
let path:NSString = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("testImage.png") as NSString
let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! as NSData
imageData.write(toFile: path as String, atomically: true)
let url:NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path as String)
let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
expression.setValue("public-read", forRequestParameter: "x-amz-acl")
expression.setValue("public-read", forRequestHeader: "x-amz-acl" )
let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()

transferUtility.uploadFile(url as URL!, bucket: bucketURL, key: myImageUploadKey , contentType: "image/png", expression: expression, completionHandler: { (task, error) in

if error != nil{
print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error")
}else{
print(task.response ?? "Response error")
}
})

expression.progressBlock = { (task: AWSS3TransferUtilityTask, progress: Progress) in
print("progress \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
}
```

application is getting crashed at let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()

So please suggest any solution. It will be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Crash logs ? error ? Anything ?

Answer (score 0):

May be this issue is coming due to AWS S3 pod updation. Please check the latest pods. Please check out this  https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios